# Whats the cheapest way to fork an ERC20 token when you have all addresses and values?

Tags: solidity, forks

If you have a copy of the mapping of the owners/allowance of the tokens you'd like to fork.

I couldn't find any contracts that seemed to be able to this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reconsider doing this, as you pay 20000 gas per 32 bytes of written storage.
2. Deploy a new token contract.
3. deliver the token amounts to their corresponding addresses through a corresponding contract function.

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear? It's hard to understand the point you are trying to make, is all what you're saying that you would advice against the entire forking of an ERC20 token because of the price?

Comment: Nikita is basically saying, create a function so people can manually claim their token based off the contract you want to fork.

Comment: No I'm not only not saying this, I would explicitly disencourage doing so, because then tokenholders could transfer their old tokens to a new address, and claim them in the new contract a second time. 
Also, the term forking does not apply here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(blockchain)
What I meant to say is there is no other way than recreating the users' balances in a new contract, unless the original would have some mechanisms in its code to allow to do it differently, which is not the case by default.